# Remove newline character from a digit in the string using PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove a new line character in front of every digit from a string using PHP regular expression?

Example:

```
$message = "
My Number is \n
0\n
7\n
8\n
9\n
Come Home\n
"
```

Becomes:

```
$message = "
My number is\n
0789\n
Come Home\n
"
```

This is what I have but it delete the everything

`$message = trim(preg_replace('\d+\s+', '', $message),'\n');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this php code:

```bash
$message = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\R+(?=\d)/', '', $message);
```

This will match 1+ of any line breaks if it is followed and preceded by a digit.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yzPUPb/1)

Comment: it still works if we remove + after \R

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
\d\K\R+(?=\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d` Match a single digit
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\R+` Match 1+ unicode newline sequences
- `(?=\d)` Positive lookahead, assert a digit directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7VSz1a/1)

```
$message = preg_replace('/\d\K\R+(?=\d)/', '', $message);
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/DvUsI).